# Android WebView complains of untrusted certificate but it is trusted in all other browsers

Tags: android, ssl, certificate, android-webview, android-security

My app opens a link to an external website inside a webview. We do not control that external website. It works fine if I open this link in a mobile browser, or in a browser on PC etc. The certificate is "trusted" in each case. However in Android webview I get "Untrusted Certificate" error, and google policy does not allow me to simply ignore the error. What can be this issue? Is this a bug in Webview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers, in general, handle certificates a little bit different to work around issues as the one you encountered. I'm not familiar with browsers internals to point what is exactly different but I suggest they hold a list of trusted Certificate Authorities (CA) that is updated regularly, more frequently than a list of trusted CAs stored on the device.

Received certificates can be trusted:

- by the Android OS;
- by the app (see below how). I guess this is the alternative option browsers use.

You will have to work around this issue by providing modified `SSLContext`. How to provide modified SSLContext [can be found here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa).

*This is not your case, but the issue can also arise when a certificate is self-signed. This is what I've encountered when developing applications and connecting to TLS enabled backend that uses a self-signed certificate.*

Comment: Hey, yes, the problem seems to be the top level certificate to be self-trusted, which is unknown to the trust store on the device. However not seeing how this certificate is trusted in browsers still.

Comment: @breakline, glad the answer helped. "However not seeing how this certificate is trusted in browsers still" - that is interesting. What is the address of this web page so I could try to send a request to it? Maybe I'll be able to tell why it is trusted by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is adfs specific, but Microsoft has documented a way to analyze this and fix this on their servers:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/adal-authenticate-android-devices-fail I know you said you don't have control over the website, but maybe this will help you gain insight into the root cause of the problem.  They suggest using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html which will tell you some common certificate issues.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).